# Is there a way to return a variable's name from an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that contains variables that could change position and I want to create a for loop that checks to see if a specific variable's length equals zero. I would rather not have to target the variable's position in the array, as it could change.

So, is there any way to target a variable in the array by the variable's name?

Comment: It would be amazingly useful to see this array and expected output.

Comment: My question is pretty straight forward, and I'm not looking for help with the output. I didn't think it was necessary to show code for something that might not be possible.

Comment: Arrays don't contain variables, they have properties that contain values. Posting some code (even not working code or pseudo code) will help in deciphering what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Also not knowing your grasp of JS, your Array might be our JS Object or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary is what you want.

```
var myDict = {x:"firstVariable", y:"second", z: ""}
 //check length
 for (key in myDict.keys()) {
     if (len(myDict[key]) == 0) {
       //Do something
     }
 }
```

Store your values with the variable names as the key, then just test the length of the value for each key.

Comment: That's not JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, should be fixed

Comment: While this did not work for me, it definitely helped me realize that object properties could be looped through. I ultimately found an answer that worked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object

Answer (score 1):

Arrays normally store their data under number indexes like 0 1, 2, n so no. Store your variables in an Object using keys and access your vars using that keys with something like:

```
var data = {varName: var1, varName2: var2};
data['varName'] = //do your thing
```

Answer (score -1):

You can access dynamically.

```
var personDetails = {name:"stanze", location: "earth" };
var p1="name";
var p2="location";
console.log(personDetails[p1]); //will print stanze
console.log(personDetails[p2]); //will print earth
```

Answer (score -1):

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` returns an array whose elements are strings corresponding to the enumerable and non-enumerable properties found directly upon obj.

```
// Array-like object
var obj = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c' };
print(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).sort()); // prints '0,1,2'

var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
print(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(arr).sort()); // prints '0,1,2,length'

// Printing property names and values using Array.forEach
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function(val, idx, array) {
  print(val + ' -> ' + obj[val]);
});
```

[Userful Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)